# WSO2 API manager with keycloak using other realm than master

Tags: wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

According to the [docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/), wso2 api manager uses the `master` realm of keycloak.

I tried to use other realm with the same configuration, but it doesn't work. It is the only difference that a `Realm Roles` called `admin` is available in the `master` realm but not in other realms. I'm not sure whether it is reason or the `api manager` could only work with the `master` realm.

The following is the error message when generating keys using other realms than `master`:

```
[2021-10-15 16:41:38,804] ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
feign.FeignException$Forbidden: [403 ] during [POST] to [http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/wso2/clients-registrations/openid-connect] [DCRClient#createApplication(ClientInfo)]: [{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":"Forbidden"}]
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:199) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:177) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy456.createApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.keycloak.client.KeycloakClient.createApplication(KeycloakClient.java:134) ~[keycloak.key.manager_2.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:154) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:125) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:121) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:65) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody138(APIConsumerImpl.java:4219) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:4080) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:744) [classes/:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:129) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at ...
[2021-10-15 16:41:38,815] ERROR - ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor Error occurred when updating the status of the Application creation process
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException_aroundBody84(APIUtil.java:1971) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1968) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:183) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:121) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:65) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody138(APIConsumerImpl.java:4219) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:4080) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:744) [classes/:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:129) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at ...
Caused by: feign.FeignException$Forbidden: [403 ] during [POST] to [http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/wso2/clients-registrations/openid-connect] [DCRClient#createApplication(ClientInfo)]: [{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":"Forbidden"}]
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:199) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:177) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy456.createApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.keycloak.client.KeycloakClient.createApplication(KeycloakClient.java:134) ~[keycloak.key.manager_2.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:154) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    ... 63 more
[2021-10-15 16:41:38,817] ERROR - APIConsumerImpl Could not execute Workflow
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:81) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:65) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody138(APIConsumerImpl.java:4219) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:4080) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:744) [classes/:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:129) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.7.jar:3.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.34.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException_aroundBody84(APIUtil.java:1971) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1968) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:183) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:121) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    ... 59 more
Caused by: feign.FeignException$Forbidden: [403 ] during [POST] to [http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/wso2/clients-registrations/openid-connect] [DCRClient#createApplication(ClientInfo)]: [{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":"Forbidden"}]
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:199) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:177) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy456.createApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.keycloak.client.KeycloakClient.createApplication(KeycloakClient.java:134) ~[keycloak.key.manager_2.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:154) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:125) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:121) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.0.174.jar:?]
    ... 59 more
[2021-10-15 16:41:38,819] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mentioned error is produced when not having enough permissions to create clients in the configured realm of the Keycloak.

The `Realm Management` related roles need to be assigned to the service account of the client when using a custom realm than `master`. The `admin` role will only be available to the `master` realm. Therefore, perform the following steps to overcome the forbidden response

1. Sign in to the Keycloak using the Admin credentials
2. Go to your custom realm which you have created to configure with the API Manager
3. Open the Client which you have created and move to the `Service Account Roles` tab
4. Under `Client Roles` select `realm-management` and add the necessary roles to create and manage clients.

   For example: assign `create-client`, `manage-clients`, `query-clients`, and `view-clients`.
5. Save the configurations
6. Restart both API Manager & Keycloak and try out the scenario